# Exposing element outside modal-backdrop in CSS Bootstrap jquery modal

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using CSS Bootstrap's Modal feature, and it's working perfectly. However, I want to add a functionality that while the modal dialog is open and the rest of the web page is covered up by the .modal-backdrop, one of the outside elements from a different place within the scope of the page's structure can be exposed on top of the backdrop:

```
<div id="outside-element">
  I want this element exposed even while the modal is active,
  upon clicking the button in the modal dialog box
</div>

<div id="help-box" class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-show="true" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="help-label" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              Click this button to show the outside element:
              <button type="button" class="btn" aria-hidden="true" id="test-item">Click it!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
     $('#test-item').click(function() {
        $('#outside-element').attr('style','zIndex:1041');
     });
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

As you can see in my current attempt above, I'm setting the z-index of the outside element to 1041, which is one higher than the .modal-backdrop setting (1040). This is not accomplishing what I want it to (namely, placing the #outside-element on top of the modal backdrop), even though the code is sound and "working" (that is, it's definitively modifying the z-index).

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you have a fiddle to show your code in a way that we can run it and see what's going on.

You will need to include the position of the element, for a z-index to take effect:

```
#outside-element {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1041;
}
```

Comment: I guess I was expecting there to be an answer to the CSS Bootstrap Modal feature in general, not as if something was specific to my code (since my code is basically more or less directly from the Modal feature within the Bootstrap framework). I did try the "position:relative" suggestion above to no avail. Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

The .modal-backdrop has a z-index of 1040, but the .modal itself (#help-box) has a z-index of 1050, so if your outside element needs to be in front of the backdrop *and* in front of the dialog, you'll have to give it a z-index of 1051 rather than 1041.

If it only needs to be in front of the backdrop, but will not be overlapping with the dialog, then a z-index of 1041 should work, but, as @uapuap mentioned, you'll also need to give it a position, like `position: relative`.

Here's a fiddle showing it working, with the outside element in front of the backdrop only, with a z-index of 1041 and `position: relative`:

http://jsfiddle.net/fgyja20w/