# angular-loading-bar placement and backdrop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using this [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar) to show a spinner when the user has to wait, but I am having big trouble with the placement of it, it's barely visible.

I have these configs on the module

```
.config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function(cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = false;
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.parentSelector = '#loading-bar-container';
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.spinnerTemplate = '<div><span class="fa fa-spinner"></div>';
}]);
```

and then I place this, in the html where I want it to show

```
<div id="loading-bar-container"></div>
```

This is works, but it's still not very visible, is it possible to make it act like a modal, or popup?

I am using [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and have some modals, so when the user makes a promise inside a modal the spinner is under it (on main body element, where 'loading-bar-container' div is), so in this case it's not visible at all, is it possible to make it 'pop out'?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this problem is about positioning of your div, this is not problem of the angular-loading-bar.

Try to use z-index and make your div always on top (above the modals).

Without more code or fiddle it's hard to say more...

**EDIT:**   Here are some older questions which can help you:

[How can I set an element over Twitter's Bootstrap modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194382/how-can-i-set-an-element-over-twitters-bootstrap-modal)

[Exposing element outside modal-backdrop in CSS Bootstrap jquery modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691722/exposing-element-outside-modal-backdrop-in-css-bootstrap-jquery-modal)

Comment: I will try and make a fiddle of it, the z-index did no difference, still below the modals